# May I know what are the format of the current ip addresses?

Tags: ip

I try to find the ip address of the sender in my Gmail.

I googled it and people suggests to look for the "received: from"

I expected to see something XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX

But I see something AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDD::EEE

Is it an ipV6 address?

Does any other format of ip address?

Comment: That is clearly [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally correct.

If you see something like `AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDD::EEE`, multiple numbers and letters separated by colons, it is an IPv6 address.

On the contrary, IPv4 looks like `12.34.56.78`, only containing numbers and separated by dots.

Currently, there are only those two types of IP addresses. Other address formats exist, however of course, for other protocols (IPX, ARP, ...)

Comment: it must be noted that `12.34.56.78`, `12.34.14414`, `12.2242638` and `203569230` are all the same `IPv4` addresses

Comment: Hah! Yes, very good, almost forgot about that.